# Trying to dynamically create a URL using a v-for loop and object properties but getting a GET error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

An object has some properties and 6 of them are called `item0, item1, item2, item3, item4 and item5`. I want to render 6 images using those properties values in the URL and the way I see it, I could either copy the image element 6 times and just change the item number like this:

```
<img v-if='match.mainParticipant.stats.item0' :src="'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/' + $store.getters.version + '/img/item/' + match.mainParticipant.stats.item0 + '.png'" alt="">
<img v-if='match.mainParticipant.stats.item1' :src="'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/' + $store.getters.version + '/img/item/' + match.mainParticipant.stats.item1 + '.png'" alt="">
<img v-if='match.mainParticipant.stats.item2' :src="'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/' + $store.getters.version + '/img/item/' + match.mainParticipant.stats.item2 + '.png'" alt="">
<img v-if='match.mainParticipant.stats.item3' :src="'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/' + $store.getters.version + '/img/item/' + match.mainParticipant.stats.item3 + '.png'" alt="">
<img v-if='match.mainParticipant.stats.item4' :src="'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/' + $store.getters.version + '/img/item/' + match.mainParticipant.stats.item4 + '.png'" alt="">
<img v-if='match.mainParticipant.stats.item5' :src="'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/' + $store.getters.version + '/img/item/' + match.mainParticipant.stats.item5 + '.png'" alt="">
```

Or I could just make a v-for loop and loop over the numbers 0-5 like this:

```
<img v-for="i in 6" :src="'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/' + $store.getters.version + '/img/item/' + match.mainParticipant.stats.item + (i - 1) + '.png'" alt="">
```

You might notice that I'm looping through 1-6 but that's because v-for loop starts from 1 for some reason. This is why I subtract 1 later. Sadly for some reason this code doesn't successfully get the images and in the console I get the error:

```
GET http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.16.1/img/item/undefined4.png 403 (Forbidden)
```

Obviously the undefined4 should be item4 instead in order for this to work, but I can't figure out why the URL becomes like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it's written at the moment you're accessing a property called `match.mainParticipant.stats.item`, which will be `undefined`. You're then adding a number on the end of that value, giving you `undefined4`, etc.

You need to use square brackets to access properties dynamically.

So:

```js
match.mainParticipant.stats['item' + (i - 1)]
```

or with backticks:

```js
match.mainParticipant.stats[`item${i - 1}`]
```